# How to recover an Ubuntu Server which has partial permanent data loss?

Tags: ubuntu, disaster-recovery, data-recovery

I have an Ubuntu Server which root partition is on a raid 0 were one HDD had data loss / broken sectors. The data loss only impacts 1-2 % of the total data on that root partition however the server either doesn't boot correctly and only starts BusyBox or it does boot but is very slow and shows a lot of errors like `end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector xxxxxxxx`.

Also the server has no big importance and only does some maintenance tasks without critical data involved (otherwise there wouldn't have been a raid 0) it still would be nice to recover its configuration so that I don't have to install and configure everything again.

Trying to fix everything temporary with `fsck` doesn't help and I've also tried to clone the disk with `dd` and similar tools which also didn't achieve anything (I have the feeling the clones are in even worse condition than the actual partition which is still on the bad raid 0).

However I do know that for example everything in `/etc/` and in `/home/`is perfectly fine. So my question is what is the best way to recover an Ubuntu Server form such kind of data loss?
My idea would be either to use one of the broken dd clones and overwrite linux kernel files and what else would be needed from the server installation DVD of the same version of Ubuntu Server. Or to install a new Ubuntu Server of the same version and copy the correct config files of the old partition back into the new system. However i'm not sure what's better, which data exactly would be needed in either case and if there maybe are tools for such tasks. So any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably best to boot off an installation disk in rescue mode.

Answer (score 1):

First off you don't want to boot the server anymore as to not cause writes to the disk. Each write can reduce your chances of successfully recovering the data. The `fsck` was a very bad idea.

Now you need to take raw images of the drives. Unless it's a pure software RAID like using `mdadm`, I wouldn't recommend using the same system for it - if it's a true hardware RAID or even a "fake" RAID but not managed by the OS, I'm afraid booting it will make the RAID controller itself attempt to write to the disks and damage them even more.

Boot on a Linux disc or on an existing Linux installation on other drives, and use `ddrescue` to take images of the disks. The process can be very slow and take days, but in the end you'll have as much good data as you can.

Once you have the images, you only need to work on them. If you don't plan on sending the original drives to a data recovery company, you can throw them away now.

If it's an `mdadm` raid, you can directly operate off the images by making them become loop devices and `mdadm --assemble`-ing them as if they were real drives. Then, mount the partition in read-only mode and attempt to `cp` all you can.

You can make multiple copies of the images and try different options. I'm not sure whether an `fsck` would help, but given you don't loose anything as you can always start over on clean copies of the images, you can always try it. Also, the fact that the underlying drives (well, loop devices backed by images) are good and will accept writes may make the `fsck` actually succeed.

If it's a hardware RAID, whether true or fake, the best way would be to buy drives identical to the failed ones, `dd` the images to it, put them back in the affected machine (for the RAID controller to reassemble them as usual) and boot off a Linux CD. Then, mount the partition in read-only and try to `cp` the data to a known good drive or to the network (NFS, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do something like that:

1. Clone the entire disk content to a working disk. Use [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/), or Norton Ghost if you have the licence. It may take a long time, but is crucial.
2. Check the integrity of the package manager database.
3. Check the integrity of packages itself, using for example `debsums`.
4. Force reinstall those that are broken.

That would fix the system itself, but would leave the configuration files (/etc for example), and other data. There is no easy way to fix that. You would have to do it on file to file basis.